# Extra byte in the TheDAO v1 bytecode

Tags: the-dao, evm

I tried decompiling the [TheDAO v1 bytecode](https://github.com/slockit/DAO/wiki/The-DAO-v1.0-Code) with disasm and it seems to fail for me. I entered the TheDAO bytecode [here](https://etherscan.io/opcode-tool) and found that the last instruction was :

```
[10836] PUSH16 0xc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e5
```

As you can see the bytecode ends with `f3e5` and it seems to ignore the last byte `63`. When I remove this last byte from the TheDAO bytecode and try running it through disasm again, it works properly.

Can someone explain what is the purpose of the last byte (`63`) there?

I am using disasm packaged with ethereum-go in release 1.3.6.

This is the error I get when I run theDAO bytecode through disasm:

```
<code>...
10819  CODESIZE
10820  PUSH16  => c84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e5
10837  PUSH4panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range   
goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x598e80, 0xc42000c110)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.main()
        /root/go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/disasm/main.go:45 +0x43e
</code>
```

And this is the error with the evm disasm v1.6.0 - https://pastebin.com/zx48s5ax

Comment: Could you describe "seems to fail" in more detail?

Comment: In particular, the commands used, and versions. (Also, did you mean `evmdis` when writing `disasm`?..)

Comment: (`disasm` is the "official" disassembler in the "Geth and Tools" combined package.)

Comment: @NoelMaersk I updated the question with the error I get and the version of disasm I am using

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The end of the code might be used as "data area", i.e. code that is never executed but might be read. The Solidity optimizer for example has a stage where it looks at all constants (i.e. PUSH instructions) and tries several methods to optimize them. One of them is to move the constant to the end of the code and use CODECOPY to retrieve it. This is especially efficient if the same long constant is used in many places.

Comment: So does this mean that evm disasm is unable to handle these optimizations done by the solidity optimizer?

Comment: filed an issue here regarding this - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14376

Thanks!