# What are remappings and how do they work in solidity?

Tags: contract-development, solc, import

How can they be used with solc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the docs on [Layout of a Solidity Source File](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.11/layout-of-source-files.html).

The solidity compiler can only reference files that exist **locally** on your computer. So importing directly from GitHub (as an example) is not possible.

Now, let's imagine you want to use OpenZeppelin's amazing library of smart contracts, [@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package](https://github.com/openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-ethereum-package):

```
pragma solidity 0.5.11;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract MyContract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    ...
}
```

If you're using [truffle](https://trufflesuite.com), this is easy-peasy. You just run `truffle compile` and the imports are magically sorted  out for you.

If you want to use `solc`, things get a bit more complicated. You have to specify the following:

- "prefix" = the path that's used in your smart contract, i.e. "@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package"
- "target" = the absolute path of OpenZeppelin's contracts downloaded on your computer

The format looks like this:

```
solc prefix=target ./MyContract.sol
```

Let's plug & play the paths:

```
solc --bin @openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package=/Your/Absolute/Path/To/@openzeppelin/contracts-ethereum-package ./MyContract.sol
```

(I specified `--bin` so that the compiler will print the bytecode in your terminal)

If you downloaded the OpenZeppelin library via npm, it should be located in the "node_modules" folder at the root of your repo.

Caveats:

- If you don't have the `solc` compiler, check out the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#installing-the-solidity-compiler) to ensure you get it right for your operating system.
- Do NOT use npm/node to install the compiler, since it has less features and remappings don't work.
- Different tools may treat remappings differently. At the time of writing this answer, [sol-compiler@3.1.13](https://sol-compiler.com) was generating a different [data area](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/15289/24693) at the end of the contract bytecode than [truffle@5.0.33](https://trufflesuite.com).